# What is the difference between drop and delete database?

Tags: sql

What is the difference between drop and delete database?

Comment: Which DB engine are you using?

Comment: while you are looking at "delete" and "drop", you might want to take a look at "truncate".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Difference between DELETE and DROP commands](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/difference_between_truncate_delete_and_drop_commands)

> **Delete:** The DELETE command is used to
>   remove rows from a table. A WHERE
>   clause can be used to only remove some
>   rows. If no WHERE condition is
>   specified, all rows will be removed.
>   After performing a DELETE operation
>   you need to COMMIT or ROLLBACK the
>   transaction to make the change
>   permanent or to undo it. Note that
>   this operation will cause all DELETE
>   triggers on the table to fire.
>
> **Drop:** The DROP command removes a table
>   from the database. All the tables'
>   rows, indexes and privileges will also
>   be removed. No DML triggers will be
>   fired. The operation cannot be rolled
>   back.

Comment: Please give credit when you copy paste from some other source !!
http://www.orafaq.com/faq/difference_between_truncate_delete_and_drop_commands

Answer (score 5):

Simply: a `DELETE` command removes matching rows, a `DROP` command removes the entire table.

Comment: Better yet, all matching rows.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I was looking for the answer myself, and since I believe the OP has asked about dropping or deleting the database, rather than tables or content, I thought I'd chip in.

Both will delete the database, but both could involve more than one step if you want to **completely** remove the database and associated artefacts.

## **DELETE**

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio, you can delete the database by right clicking on the database and selecting Delete. The resulting dialog offers a couple of checkboxes :

1. 'Delete backup and restore history information for databases'
2. 'Close Existing connections'

If you don't tick 'Delete backup and restore history..' , those files will remain on the server unless you manually get rid of them.
'Close Existing connections' is a good idea, otherwise you may get an error telling you the database is still in use (even if it's just you, while you're trying to delete it)

## **DROP**

The SQL Command 'DROP' alone will not remove everything. You will still need to also remove the backup history, and set the database to 'single user mode' - or it may complain the database is still in use, as above.

```
--Remove backup history
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'YourDBName'
GO
USE [master]
GO
--close all the open connections to your database
ALTER DATABASE [YourDBName] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
USE [master]
GO
--remove the actual database 
DROP DATABASE [YourDBName]
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete removes content and drop the structure of a database.

Answer (score 2):

**Delete** removes content of table.**Drop** removes content and structure of table.**Delete** can be rolled back but **Drop** can not be rolled back

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are using MS SQL
Then if you want to delete the whole `Table` then you would use:

DROP TABLE MyTable

This would delete the whole table and its constraints

To delete any specific row you would use:

DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE id=5

This would delete the row with the id = 5
If no conditions are matched it would delete all rows

Answer (score 0):

`DROP` removes the entire table and associated objects from the catalog, requiring you to create all the indexes and constraints from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Drop in a function that physically removes and particular table or a column. The table struction remails same. If you want to see the structure, you can write this
desc tablename; and the structure will be same after dropping the table.
Delete function permanantly deletes the table or a column, the structure of the table also.